# Reactor Pattern for Consuming Whole Stream and Starting New Flux from Result

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactor

Is there a reactor pattern to consume a whole stream and then create a new flux from the result? I have a flux sourced from a file, which may be larger than memory. In the middle of the stream, I need to perform some aggregate operation, such as sorting or grouping, which cannot be done entirely in-memory. I then need to continue processing the stream from the result of the grouping/sorting operation. Is there a reactor-ish way of doing it in a single Flux?

`Flux<T> -> file -> grouping / sorting -> Flux<T>`

The only way I can think of is through multiple fluxes

```java
flux.map(t -> ...).doOnNext(t -> writeToFile(...));
externalProcessFile();
Flux<T> f = Flux.using(() -> Files.lines(Paths.get("/path/to/file")), Flux::fromStream, BaseStream::close).map(t -> nextFunc(t))...
```

Comment: Flux::flatMap does that.

Comment: if the file doesn't fit in memory, how do you expect "sorting the file" can happen in memory ?

Comment: @SimonBaslé it's not going to be sorted in memory, it's going to be externally sorted with disk as an overflow

Comment: @K.Nicholas flatmap doesn't consume the whole stream though

Comment: You question is not clear.